# tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing a `UITableView` within my `UIViewController`. I have been able to get my text to display with a custom `UITableViewCell`, but I can not find a way to put spacing between my cells.

I have tried implementing `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`, but it seems that it is not called as I have tried to put in a print statement to see if it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you set the tableview's delegate to be your viewcontroller (and make sure that your viewcontroller conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol):

```
class CustomTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

}
```

Results in:

[image: result]

Comment: I do have this. Thank you though

Comment: I did try implementing your method. My root problem is that when I begin even typing "heightForHeaderInSection", the autocomplete does not pop up. Even though it did pop up for me when I typed in other UITableView methods. It's as though the function is not part of the library for some reason. I have found a workaround though which does serve my purpose and I will post it

Comment: Did you make your viewcontroller conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol? Take a look at the first line of my solution...

Comment: This actually was the answer when I came back and looked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

i had problem that **heightForHeaderInSection** was not working, but after i set viewForHeaderInSection then the height works properly. Make sure you have set the view header in section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 44
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `viewDidLoad()` :

```
let HEADER_HEIGHT = 100
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(HEADER_HEIGHT))
```

Another way -

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Comment: For somer reason, tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat does not pop up for me when I begin to type it in. As though it is not part of the class. Not sure why, but I have implemented a work around where the background is transparent, and I use a label to be my background as I want with proper spacing.

Comment: @GabeGomez You can share your full code here for better understanding.